# Granting domain-wide authority to a service account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

Docs suggest that the addition of service accounts to a GApps' 3rd party oauth access list has to be done manually by domain admins:
https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Is there a way to do this through an auth page instead?

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no alternative ways to give permissions to an service account for domain-wide authority at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Are there plans to add this? And also, do you have an idea about planned changes to the Marketplace api? Right now it's a pain to look at the docs with all the broken links and deprecated stuff.